# Factorising polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

Is there some fast way to determine whether a polynomial divides another in $\mathbb{Z}_2$? Is there some fast way to factor polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ into irreducible polynomials?

Is there a fast way to find $n$ such that a given polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ divides $x^n-1$?

Could there be a strategy/checklist to check this as fast as possible?

Please help me.

Comment: No and no, in general. Particular cases are other matter.

Comment: Even if all coefficients are 0 or 1?

Comment: Over $Z_2$ those are the only values for the coefficients.

Comment: I know -.- I just asked in case he didnt notice

Comment: Well, you could program a computer to try dividing by every possible polynomial, of which there aren't *that* many

Comment: sure but I am asking cause I have an exam tomorrow where I wont have a computer....

Comment: @vounoo It might depend on what somebody considers "fast": can you see or check "fast" whether $\;x^2+x+1\;$ divides $\;x^5+x^4+1\;$ ? The only way I can think of is to actually divide the latter by the former...and yes: over a field with two elements this is easier than over other fields, yet it still requires some work.

Comment: @Timbuc Sure I agree with you but let me show you where the problem with that is .. if the former (in another example) does not divide the latter. Is there a way to realize this fast?

Comment: One thing that might help for the specific case is that (if I remember correctly) $x^n-1 \,|\, x^m-1$ iff $n\,|\,m$.

Comment: If you have an exam tomorrow, then the thing to do is to go over the class materials, to see whether there is anything there about fast ways to do these things. If so, then you know what to do. If not, then there won't be a question expecting you to do it.

Comment: That is not true, it is an optional course in algebra. Most people have studied this things in other courses. So they are expected to know these things. I havent taken any other similar courses. The test is on coding theory. You can apply this stuff to make cyclic codes. but I am unfamiliar with this stuff. That is why I am asking here

Answer (score 1):

To check for divisibility is easy: since $\mathbb Z_2$ is a discrete valuation ring, for any two polynomials $f, g$, $f$ divides $g$ iff it divides it over the fraction field $\mathbb Q_2$ and the content of $f$ divides the content of $g$. Testing this is just Euclidean division, which is “fast” enough by any definition.

To factor into irreducibles, you first want to write the [Newton polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polygon) of your polynomial; this gives you a first factorization (by Hensel's lemma). Each segment of this polynomial, however, gives you a product of irreducibles; factoring this is then equivalent to factoring over the residue field $\mathbb F_2$. (This is the case of a horizontal segment of the Newton polygon; you can bring a non-horizontal segment to this case by substituting $x \leftarrow c x$, where $c$ has the appropriate valuation).

In total, full factorization over $\mathbb Z_2$ should be at most cubic, which is still probably reasonably fast.